# Rails Turbolinks Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Hi im new to rails and I am getting a turbolink error when using link_to.

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '<' is not a valid attribute name.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   root 'static_pages#home'
   get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
end
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

home.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "About", about_path%>
```

Comment: Do you need a space after `about_path`?

Comment: Tried still getting the same error thanks for the help though.

Comment: Error seems not an turbolinks error, are you using angular js?

Comment: What's the *full* stack trace for this error?

Comment: There is no rails error the error is in the developer console when I click the link the url changes but the page doesn't get loaded unless I hit enter to force the reload. It says the error is within turbolink. turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js:6

Comment: What is the HTML of the about page?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out @jrocc

Comment: @Alizoh This was awhile ago so I don't really remember I believe I had a typo that I didn't see.

Comment: @jrocc Thanks for the reply, I found the issue at the end in an obscure syntax error as well.